# wasd change in aframe

Tags: javascript, aframe

Hi I am new to aframe trying to create buttons on the screen (like the full-screen VR mode) to mimic wasd controls.

I tried info on this  [Link](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls#input-devices) it gave me some hint regarding this but did not solve my query.

If you guys have any idea please let me know.

and also I tried broadcasting keyboard events they did not help either.

here is the camera code i tried this but nothing happened
                 `<a-camera id="myCamera" universal-controls="movementControls: custom, touch;">
    <a-cursor id="myCursor" color="blue"></a-cursor>
</a-camera>`

-Thanks

Comment: Share some code in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If You want to move the camera when clicking at a button, just make a listener in a component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('click-handler',{
init:function(){
   let cam = document.querySelector('[camera]');
   this.el.addEventListener('click',function(e){
         let pos = cam.getAttribute('position');
         pos.z++;
         cam.setAttribute('position',pos);
   });
 });
```

which moves the camera forward on click.
If You want to make it smooth like in the wasd controls, with 'friction', and some kind od speed, You need to make it in the `tick()`, where You define Your speed as `if(speed>0)speed=acc+speed-friction`, and make a acc peek once You click the button. You can increase the acc while holding the button, so the movement will be even smoother.

---

I found the universal-controls useful, when You move using a vive/other controller, not by looking at some entities.

Comment: how do I manage change in camera angle I mean It can point towards anywhere, suppose its pointing in zx direction then how am I supposed to calculate the direction... One way is subtract the camera and cursor vector to get the direction but what if I am not using cursor then how will I calculate the direction vector?.... Thanks for helping me everytime adam. :)

Comment: As far as i know, managing the camera is by setting/getting the document.querySelector('[camera]') rotation attribute. Rotating the camera also rotates the coordinate system, so moving the camera 'forward' is executed by decreasing its 'z' position